# Перемещение Panel

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

На форме несколько панелей, например, 5 штук, все они расположены на некоторой высоте Top. Мне нужно перетащить, допустим, Panel1 на Panel4 и чтобы они поменяли места расположения между собой. Я делал это с помощью DragDrop, но не совсем получалось желаемое.

Comment: Ну, тут просто, мне кажется, события перетаскивания обрабатываешь и меняешь координаты местами у этих панелей. Как-то так... делфи нет под рукой, потому ничего более конкретного посоветовать не смогу тебе.

Comment: Так, а что получалось-то?